# Accessing custom headers in aws apigateway integration response (custom lambda integration)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an api gateway endpoint which sits in front of a lambda (does not use lambda proxy integration, uses custom lambda integration). The lambda returns the following:

```
module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

 const response = {
     statusCode: 200,
     body: JSON.stringify({
         message: 'some message'
     }),
     headers: {
         bob: 'this is bob'
     },
 };

 return response;
};
```

I am trying to access the header bob like so in the integration request: integration.response.header.bob. This doesn't work. I can get it out from the body like so integration.response.body.headers.bob. I assume the former doesn't work because I am not using lambda proxy integration? Also noticed that I can retrieve integration.response.header.Content-Type. Can someone please explain how to add custom headers passed from the lambda like in above code properly (or is the only option getting it from body like I tried)?

Answer (score 0):

Integration headers (integration.header.header-name) are the headers that the Lambda Service sends to API Gateway. We do not have control over these headers. These are standard headers - Content-Type, Date etc. and are a part of the "Endpoint response headers".

Whereas, custom headers that you control are part of the "Endpoint response body". To answer your question - yes, you have to retrieve the custom headers from the body.

Check the below snippet of API Gateway execution logs to see the difference.

```
Mon Jun 22 04:28:51 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response headers: {Date=Mon, 22 Jun 2020 04:28:51 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=72, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=4d6d78b5-bb45-4e8d-893f-a409563e493c, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amz-Executed-Version=$LATEST, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-5ef03382-d494d01d575754f5b551dfd3;sampled=0}
Mon Jun 22 04:28:51 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"statusCode": 200, "body": "Hello!", "headers": {"bob": "this is bob"}}
Mon Jun 22 04:28:51 UTC 2020 : Method response body after transformations: {"statusCode": 200, "body": "Hello!", "headers": {"bob": "this is bob"}}
Mon Jun 22 04:28:51 UTC 2020 : Method response headers: {X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-5ef03382-d494d01d575754f5b551dfd3;Sampled=0, Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*, Content-Type=application/json}
Mon Jun 22 04:28:51 UTC 2020 : Successfully completed execution
Mon Jun 22 04:28:51 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 200
```